# Print command line parameter on console

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I want to pass a file name to my programm. If I type it in the terminal it works. But if I pass it as a command line parameter it doesn`t print the string in the end. Just something like: "²☺"
Any ideas why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char *nameDatei[100];
    
    if(argv[1] != NULL) {
        nameDatei[100] = argv[1];
    } else {
        printf("type in the name of the file: ");
        scanf("%s", nameDatei);
    }

    printf("%s", &nameDatei);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indicies in C start from 0. Accessing `nameDatei[100]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Also you want to print a string but pass pointer to array of pointers.

Comment: Thank you I found the problem. I wanted to declare nameDatei as a String not an array. Just delete the *

Comment: You cannot assign a string in that simple way. You need to copy it, for example via `strcpy()` or any safer function.

Comment: You neither need nor want to copy the data.  You should never copy data unless you absolutely must.  eg `const char *path; char nameDate[100]; if( argc > 1 ){ path = argv[1]; } else { path = nameDate; if( 1 == scanf("%99s", nameDate) ....`

Answer (score 0):

It only works "by accident" when you type the name at the terminal, and that's because you are either ignoring compiler warnings or using an obsolete compiler (any compiler which is not complaining about the code is obsolescent, though GCC 11.2.0 seems to accept it unless you pass warning options such as `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`).

- You pass a `char *(*)[100]` to `printf()` but tell it that the argument is a `char *`
- You pass a `char **` to `scanf()` but tell it that the argument is a `char *`
- You try to access element 100 of an array of size 100, which is one too many.

You happen to have `100 * sizeof(char *)` bytes to hold the name, which is where the accident comes in, but that's not the correct type.

You need code more like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *nameDatei;
    char nameBuffer[100];

    if (argv[1] != NULL)
        nameDatei = argv[1];
    else
    {
        printf("type in the name of the file: ");
        if (scanf("%99s", nameBuffer) != 1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to read file name\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        nameDatei = nameBuffer;
    }

    printf("%s\n", nameDatei);

    return 0;
}
```

I called the source `cla61.c` and the program `cla61`.  A couple of sample runs:

```
$ cla61 abyssinian-coffee
abyssinian-coffee
$ cla61 
type in the name of the file: abyssinian-coffee
abyssinian-coffee
$
```

Don't copy command-line arguments unless you are going to modify them.  But it's legitimate to make a new variable point to a command-line argument.  And when there isn't a command-line argument, you need to allocate space for the replacement value — the value read from the terminal in this example.